# Convert string to char in c++ no complete process

Tags: c++

this is my string variable:

`string Image_Content = " ╪ ß Exif  II*            ∞ Ducky     P   ßhttp://www.com/xap/1.0/          ε Adobe d└    █ ä ";`

but when i want to convert this to const char* in c++, like this:

`const char* New_Char = _strdup(Image_Content.c_str());`

i just get this content in New_Char variable:

`cout << New_Char;`

and this is my result:

`╪ ß`

not all content in string convert to char !!!!!!!!!!! why ? what is the problem?

At the end i want to get the full content of a image with this:

`ifstream fin("w.jpg", ios::in | ios::binary);`
`ostringstream oss;`
`oss << fin.rdbuf();`
`string data(oss.str());`
`const char* New_Char = _strdup(data.c_str());`

And convert the string content to const char but when i convert it to char the only thing that show to me is ( `╪ ß`) but in string it show all content of image.

Comment: There seem to be `'\0'` characters in your string literal.

Comment: Why don't you store image contents as binary data? Because strings are for storing strings of characters, they are not meant to store binary data. And I am sure that images are not supposed to be viewed as strings at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a wild guess based on the symptoms only.

A c++ string is a much more complex object than is a mere C `char *`. In this particular use case, it has a true length and can contain NULL characters, whereas *by convention* a C string (char *) is ended with a NULL. That means that every C string can be converted to a C++ std::string, but the opposite is only true if the std::string does not contain any NULL.

If you need to process the std::string as a char array, you need to use `Image_Content.data()` or `Image_Content.c_str()` (*) and use first `Image_Content.size()` characters from it. That just means that a `printf` on it will be truncated at first NULL, even if other characters exist after it.

(*) as noticed by @atkins both methods are synonyms for C++11. For C++98, both gave access to the full buffer, by only `c_str` was guaranteed to be null terminated.

Comment: According to 21.4.7.1 (string.accessors), since C++11 `string::data` and `string::c_str` are synonymous (i.e. `string::data` also returns a null-terminated char array).

Comment: now what should i do ? i need this string convert to const char* to using in socket send !!!!!!

Comment: Are you sure the socket send isn't working correctly? Your `const char*` should be pointing to memory which contains all of the data in the original string, it's just that `cout` stops when it gets to a `\0`. In your socket send, try using `Image_Content.c_str()` and set the buffer size to `Image_Content.size()`, and I think you should see all your data is transmitted.

Comment: @atkins: Since c++11, `data` and `c_str` are synonyms. For C++98, only `c_str` was guaranteed to be null terminated. But anyway, you are right, both can be used here with whatever C++ version.

Comment: @user216086: if you just need to send that through a socket, just use `write(s, Image_Content.c_str(), Image_Content.size())`. The hard part is to **receive** it, since it is not null terminated! You should first send the size (either a binary 4 bytes int in network order, or a decimal string representing the size terminated with a `\n` or a NULL) and then read a number of bytes.

Comment: I Solved the problem .... i am using (const char* New_Cont = data.c_str();) and i used this in my send process and its worked ...